# An error No such file or directory exist when i read from a file using fopen

Tags: c, linux, sockets, fopen

I am creating a simple file server in c in linux. My approach is that i am sending the name of the file from the client. The file server receives file name. And search for the file and opens it for reading. Read data from it, and send the data to client.
But the problem is that name for the file on the client side. I transfer that server. I have printed name there and it is recieved there(I mean server). But the server program does not open file with specified name. And gives me an error: no such files or directory exist.

One that i must add is that: i have created .txt file and entered in it number from 1 to 30

Comment: Could you please post the relevant parts of your code? Then people can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You should show some code, and perhaps some log output, too.

I would guess that the problem is that the server executable is running with the wrong current directory. Are you sending full path names, with directories that perhaps only exist on the client?

Comment: ./fileclientfinal.exe 127.0.0.1 1200 "firstdata.txt"
The Client fd is: 3
Enter Name For Program: danish.txt
The name of the file of the server is:danish.txt

The size of bufer is: 11
The bytes sent is: 11
The number of Bytes Recieved Is: 0
server terminated prematurallyThanks for reply. Will the error on the client is......the error log on the server side is: ./fileserverfinal.exe 1200
Client fd is: 4
The number of bytes recieved is: 11
The File To Be Transfered Is: danish.txt

open error: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Try using a debugger like `gdb` for the server. As *unwind* told you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8892256/841108), you might not be in the directory you want.

You might also, for debugging purposes, print (to `stderr`, to some logging or debugging file, or thru [`syslog`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/syslog)) the result of [getcwd(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getcwd) (or perhaps of`get_current_dir_name`) in your server before the `open` or `fopen` call.